# Upload a file in VB.NET and read the server response

Tags: vb.net, file, post, upload

I need to upload a file on a server and I need to receive the response (the url where the file was upload).

I have two things:
- URL (the site to which I have to make the request)
- Filename (the path of the file which I want to upload)

And I want to get:
- File uploaded on that server
- The response of the server

I searched for hours for a solution, but I found only source in C#, that I also tried to convert in VB.NET, but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

There are two ways you can upload a file to a server.

---

What server are you using?
if you're using a php server, you can create a directory named `upload` a file with the name `upload.php` and set it'd content to this code :

```
<?   
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo realpath("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
?>
```

on the vb.net code you should use the code below :

```
Dim Fileuri As String
Using we As New WebClient
    Dim responseArray As Byte()
    responseArray = we.UploadFile("http://www.yourdomain.com/upload.php", Filepath)
    Fileuri = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
End Using
```

---

on the other hand, you can use ftp protocole to upload files to your server :

```
Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://yourdomain.com/upload/" & Compresseduri), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Dim files() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filetoupload)

Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
strz.Write(files, 0, files.Length)
strz.Close()
strz.Dispose()
```

Best wishes,

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doesn't work. I have a PHP server and the response is in JSON. But the problem is that I haven't credential to the FTP and I haven't the PHP source. The only things that I know are that I need to upload the file via POST Method and the response will be the url where the file was uploaded. I tried your first source, but I don't know why the upload of the file doesn't work. Thanks (P.S. Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: the php source is in the answer ,the first code block, to use the PHP method you should create a file on the server and name it `upload.php` and create a folder for the uploads you may also add a password for security purpose, for the FTP credential you should find them at your host in the detail section.

Comment: I have the server, but it's not mine. I can't access to the PHP source. I need to send the file via POST Method (I know how to send a simple string, but I don't know how to send a file). My problem is the VB.NET source to do that, the PHP is ready. (P.S. I'm working at a client to a file sharing hosting)

Comment: as i said before the codes are in the description just give it a try.

Comment: I tried it, but with the first method I don't know why I receive a response from the server which indicates that the file has not been uploaded. :( I can't use the second method because I don't have the FTP credentials (the server is not mine and the admin doesn't want to tell me it). Thanks

Comment: Are sending a big file?

Comment: No, only 5 kb PNG image.

Comment: It's not an error. If the file has been uploaded I receive a string with the url where the file is located on the server, else the server sends me to the homepage, so I receive instead of the url, the HTML code of the homepage. :(

Comment: have you created the upload directory?

Comment: Yes, the PHP works great because there is also a uploader via web. I want to upload via VB.NET.

Comment: Write this code in the begenning of the form class `Imports System.Net`